# Data frame inside for loop with function for a simulation study wont work

Tags: r, function, loops

I am doing looping for my simulation study. But it did not give a nice output. I want to be able to call out again the output.
This is the function inside the looping.

```
#generate data
gen<-function(n,lambda,b0,b1){
  
  u<- runif(n,0,1)
  s1<- rexp(n,lambda)
  x<- rnorm(n,0,1)
  
  t1= -log(1-sqrt(u))/(exp(-b0 - b1*x)) #inverse method
  
  s<- 1*(t1<s1)
  t= pmin(t1,s1)
  
  data1<-data.frame(x,t,t1,s1,s)
  return(data1)
}
LLF<- function(para){

  b0=para[1]
  b1=para[2]
  
  z1= log(2*(exp(-b0 - b1*x))) - (exp(-b0 - b1*x))*t + log(1-exp(-exp(-b0 - b1*x)*t))
  
  j=sum(z1)
  return(j)
}
```

Here, I want to generate randomly for 10 times and put in the data frame. But the output only assigns number 1 to every row. I cannot call back the row I wanted.

```
for (i in 1:10){
  data2<-gen(20,0.0000001,5,1)
  x= data2$x
  t= data2$t
  mle<-maxLik(LLF,start = c(5,1))

  jj<-data.frame(mle$estimate[1],mle$estimate[2])
  
  print(jj)
}
```

Comment: so you want the jj be a data.frame with the results? right now you are overwriting the jj variable with new data.frame that captures mle$estimate[1] and [2], while discarding everything else. (well, technically you are saving mle, x, y and data2 as well, however you are overwriting these in each step. So basically your code is only saving the last iteration as the all the previous ones are overwritten.

Comment: where does `maxLik()` come from?

Comment: So how can i not overwriting it?

Comment: maxLik() is from library(maxLik)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to save the data into a data frame I will assume you want `jj` to contain the result. As your code stands you probably want to do something like:

```
#before the loop starts:
jj <- data.frame("name1" = numeric(), "name2" = numeric())

#inside the loop:
jj[i, ] <- c(mle$estimate[1],mle$estimate[2]))
```